# Cell null at cellForRowAtIndexPath objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

i have an app where im using tableView, but the instance of the row is nil at cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Here is my code:

This is TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

This is TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "ProgramCell.h"

@implementation TableViewController
{
    NSArray *arrayDays;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

    }
    arrayDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayDays count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    ProgramCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell description]);

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ProgramCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.durationLabelCell.text = @"HOLA";


    return cell;
}
@end
```

This is my CustomHell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProgramCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *durationLabelCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textViewCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *presenterLabelCell;


@end
```

This is my CustomCell.m

```
#import "ProgramCell.h"

@implementation ProgramCell


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    return self;
}


-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

I dont know what im doing wrong, if someone could help me would be great! thanks

Comment: Show us the code of ProgramCell to help you

Comment: My PrgramCell only gets the outlets from my Storyboard so i can modify them

Comment: Did you read the spec for dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier??

Answer (score 0):

You should set identifier as part of the definition of your TableViewCell.

[image]

Comment: Yes i have, but it doesn't work, its not instantiating the cell

Answer (score 0):

The way you check "cell is null" is incorrect. The `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` just returns a reusable table-view cell object located by its identifier, if not find, it'll return nil, then what

```
if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[ProgramCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```

does is to create a new cell w/ the identifier (so can u use it later).

The correct way to check whether cell is null by printing log should be

```
ProgramCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ProgramCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
NSLog(@"description = %@",[cell description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if this is related, but why do you have a reference to a table view(i.e a separate Table View variable) in a table view controller. UITableViewController implicitly provides you one instance of a UITableView.
Also try registering the cellType within the table view controllers if a prototype/dynamic class